# Libreoffice calc opens sheets with one line of unknown characters

Tags: libreoffice

Does anyone know why Libreoffice opens csv files like this for me recently? I've been having to import them into google sheets instead, where they work fine but it's a pain.
Ubuntu 20.04
LO Version: 6.4.7.2 Build ID: 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Screenshot of LO launch screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the expected character set (the top dropdown list) to UTF-16. Each character is supposed to occupy two bytes, which is intended for languages like Chinese. Regular English can do with one byte per character.

Set your character set to UTF-8 and all will be fine.

Disclaimer: my explanation above is rather simplified: in fact the situation is much more complicated than that. Search for "Unicode" if you want the full details.